# Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'type' error but type is same

Tags: c#, wcf

```
EmployeeService.EmployeeWcfClient client = new EmployeeService.EmployeeWcfClient();
EmployeeService.Employee newEmp = client.getEmployee(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text));
```

When I try to run this code I get a error saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Employee.EmployeeService.Employee' to 'Employee.EmployeeService.Employee

I don't understand what is the problem with this code. The `getEmployee` method is:

```
public Employee getEmployee(int id)
{ 
    Employee empOb = new Employee();
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBMS"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("retrieveEmp", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter();
        para.ParameterName = "@id";
        para.Value = id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(para);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            empOb.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
            empOb.name = Convert.ToString(reader["name"]);
            empOb.gender = Convert.ToString(reader["gender"]);
            empOb.date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date"]);
        }
    }

    return empOb;
}
```

Comment: We don't know what could cause the error without the getEmployee code

Comment: okay i will add the code

Comment: Did you create two different classes both named "Employee"?

Comment: Also try fully qualifying all the "Employee"s

Comment: Do you get error when you run or compile? (Looks like compile time error, but you said "run this code")

Comment: compile time error. when building the program

Comment: @TheLethalCoder can you explain me bit further please

Comment: For example instead of writing "Int32" for a variable you'd write "System.Int32"

Comment: @Optimuskck Try changing your method signature to: `public Employee.EmployeeService.Employee getEmployee(int id)`

Comment: Have you tried to do a rebuild or a clean.  I've seen this error when dlls get out of sync sometimes.

Comment: i will try to recreate the asp form from scratch and rebuild all .

Comment: finally able to fix the problem. i recreate ASP form and rebuild the solution and walah.. no longer the error .appear. TheLethalCoder Servy Alexei Siva juharr thanks :)